# error in replaceAll() method

Tags: java

i have error in `String st=str.replaceAll(" ","");`
But include the `import java.lang.String.*;`
After adding this line again same error repeated.. 
So please anyone help me to solve the error..

```
String st=str.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Comment: It would help if you'd say what the error is to start with. You don't need to import anything else. You *do* need a semi-colon though.

Comment: Please put your error message here or modify your question.

Answer (score 4):

We can't really tell what's wrong without you telling us the error message or giving us more code. Your snippet is missing a semi-colon, and relies on `str` being a definitely-assigned variable of type String, but that's all.

Sample code that works:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "hello world";
        String st = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
        System.out.println(st); // helloworld
    }
}
```

Now you just need to find the difference between your code and my code...

Comment: The difference? Your code is beautifully formatted? :-) +1 for providing a complete baseline piece of code to work from.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you properly, you used the line twice, like this:

```
// in scope of some method:
String st=str.replaceAll(" ","");
//....
String st=str.replaceAll(" ","");
```

This is not legal, because you declared a variable with the same name in the same scope twice, instead, it should be:

```
// in scope of some method:
String st=str.replaceAll(" ","");
//....
st=str.replaceAll(" ","");
```

or:

```
// in scope of some method:
String st=str.replaceAll(" ","");
//....
String st1=str.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Comment: I actually read "After adding this line again" as "I deleted it then retyped it to make sure it was right". Otherwise it doesn't explain the error when there was only one of them.